# Error "You must sign up for Amazon EC2 before you can use the Amazon EC2 console." is received when accessing EC2 console, why?

Tags: amazon-web-services

This happens when accessing EC2 console for any region.

Global services like S3, IAM and account related pages can be accessed without problems.

No AWS Organization issue, no policy issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to your email and click the link AWS management console and open an AWS account.
So, now you can access your EC2.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have skipped one or more steps during registration.

You may have received an email stating you need to complete those steps.

File a support case to receive the email again if you missed it.

Answer (score 0):

1. [image: List item]

It takes a while to AWS to verify your card details after you register a new account with AWS. It would be great if AWS would give a more sensible message.

Wait for account activation :

After you choose a Support plan, a confirmation page indicates that your account is being activated. Accounts are usually activated within a few minutes, but the process might take up to 24 hours.

[AWS create and activate account](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-and-activate-aws-account/)